# How to correctly add variable to environment or session

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, environment-variables

I work with a opensource software that I have built locally. After build the manual says to run it like this while inside the build directory

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../applicationExeFile
```

Then the application runs fine.

Now I tried to make a simple shell to call quickly without typing much (run.sh) with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

export -n LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
./applicationExeFile
```

But it seems that LD_LIBRARY_PATH does not get registered in shell as I get error regarding the application executable can not find a library that is in the same folder

```
./applicationExeFile: error while loading shared libraries: libchart.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong and how to achieve this?

Comment: What are you supposed to set it to? You seem to be setting the variable to `.`, is that what you want?

Comment: yes I need to set it to '.' as in the current directory

Comment: Why did you add `-n` to the export command? that's for *removing* a variable from the environment

Comment: What steeldriver said. Also, what current directory? The way you have it set up, it will only work if you first `cd` into the target directory and only then run the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue is that `-n` actually *un*exports a variable, it doesn't export it. See `help export`:

```
export: export [-fn] [name[=value] ...] or export -p
    Set export attribute for shell variables.
    
    Marks each NAME for automatic export to the environment of subsequently
    executed commands.  If VALUE is supplied, assign VALUE before exporting.
    
    Options:
      -f    refer to shell functions
      -n    remove the export property from each NAME
      -p    display a list of all exported variables and functions
    
    An argument of `--' disables further option processing.
    
    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless an invalid option is given or NAME is invalid.
```

Next, `.` refers to the current working directory of the process. This means that your script still needs to be run from the specific directory where your program is installed which seems a bit pointless. Just use a full path instead. If your program is at `/home/dekker/myprogram`, make your script like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/dekker/myprogram
/home/dekker/myprogram/applicationExeFile
```

Or just:

```
#! /bin/sh -
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/dekker/myprogram exec /home/dekker/myprogram/applicationExeFile
```

as there's nothing `bash`-specific, and you don't need the separate `export` statement. Using `exec` also saves a process and makes signal handling and the reporting of the exit status more reliable.

Comment: Thanks! Also about the exec I didn't know that :)

Comment: You're very welcome, @DEKKER, although the `exec` bit came from Stéphane who edited my answer, making it much better. So all credit for that bit goes to him! :)